# Google BigQuery Return Users Count

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get number of return users from Google Big Query to match with what I have in GA.

The query I wrote is:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN totals.newVisits IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Return_Visitors
FROM `table`
WHERE date='20161109'
```

But I got more return users than what I got from GA.

I found the the definition of totals.newVisits is "Total number of new users in session (for convenience). If this is the first visit, this value is 1, otherwise it is null."  That's why I used when totals.newVisits is null. 
Is my logic right?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
select
SUM(CASE WHEN totals.newVisits IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Return_Visitors
FROM `table`
where totals.visits = 1
and date = '20161109'
```

Comment: Hi Will, unfortunately, it does not work for me. I guess when the totals.visitor equals to 1, it means it's the first time visit. it's not a return_visitor. Do you have other thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Just now I realized that I wrote a different summation from yours. I just fixed that. Could you please try the query again? I used the flag `totals.visits = 1` because that's the only difference between G.A data and BigQuery. In G.A, there's a filter to consider only `total.visits = 1` so that's why we usually see less data there.

Comment: Thank you so much Will! The solution solved my problem!